# Infeasibility from adding a binary variable

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I would really appreciate any pointers here; I’ve been stuck for a while.

The issue is as such: I have a linear program that I wrote in Pyomo and, when I solve it, it runs to optimality. However, when I introduce any constraint that involves a binary variable, the solver claims infeasibility regardless of the constraint used. I’ve isolated the problem entirely and still don’t have a solution. I commented it out all my integer constraints and added the following three lines:

```
model.a = Var(within=Real)
model.b = Var(within=Binary)
model.DummyConstraint = Constraint(expr = model.a <= model.b)
```

That is, I define two new dummy variables (one binary) that don’t appear anywhere in the code along with a new constraint that involves both of them. The solver (glpk) should be able to solve the original problem to optimality exactly the same as before and then arbitrarily set the new variables ‘a’ and ‘b’ to something that satisfies the constraint (simplex would set them to both 0 or both 1).

This doesn’t work however. The problem is infeasible for some reason but only when the 3 new lines are added. I copy and pasted the 3 lines into a separate unrelated optimization problem and it works perfectly fine as expected.

Unfortunately I can’t share the rest of the formulation as it is confidential but seeing that my 2 new variables and 1 new constraint are simple and share absolutely no overlap with the rest of the problem they shouldn’t be necessary.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: To isolate is even further I initialized both values to zero. It still says infeasible. However, if I set the binary variable ‘b’ to the same as the initialized value (model.DummyConstraint = Constraint(expr = model.a <= 0)) then it solves to optimality. Again, these two variables were simply placed in the code for testing and do not appear anywhere else in the formulation. It is only infeasible if I include a binary variable in a constraint in any way, otherwise it works fine. I printed output with tee=True. It says Infeasible Primal which is clearly incorrect given that it solved earlier.

Comment: What solver are you using?

Comment: I am using glpk

Comment: I think it creates the following expression model.a <= False/True therefore you are getting infeasiblity? or are u sure that model.b is getting 0/1?